# How to place a div below a nested div?

Tags: css, html

How do I place a div below a nested div? Right now the third div (.box3) seems to overlap the second div when I want it to appear below the second div (.box2). Please see example: https://jsfiddle.net/662fwmq5/

```css
.box1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.box2 {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.box3 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  Box 1
  <div class="box2">
    Fixed income, currency, and commodities revenue was $2.65 billion ($2.21 billion expected), up 39% thanks to stronger performance in credit products, especially mortgages, as well as in rates products and client financing. Equities revenue came in at
    $954 million ($1.03 billion expected), down 17% because of lower client activity in cash and derivatives, which the firm said reflected lower market volatility.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box3">
  More than 14,000 seasonal positions were transitioned to regular, full-time roles after the holidays last year, and the company expects to increase that number this year, Amazon said on Thursday.
</div>
```

My issue is further magnified when the screen size narrows. I want the third div (.box3) to respond to screen size changes so that the third div always appears below the second div (.box2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a fixed height for `box1` - that is why the following div is overlapping the nested content.

So remove the `height` from `box1` and there you go:

```css
.box1 {
 width: 50%;
 /*height: 200px;*/
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.box2 {
 width: 80%;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: blue;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

.box3 {
 background-color: #ccc;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="box1">
 Box 1
  <div class="box2">
  Fixed income, currency, and commodities revenue was $2.65 billion ($2.21 billion expected), up 39% thanks to stronger performance in credit products, especially mortgages, as well as in rates products and client financing.
  Equities revenue came in at $954 million ($1.03 billion expected), down 17% because of lower client activity in cash and derivatives, which the firm said reflected lower market volatility.
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="box3">
  More than 14,000 seasonal positions were transitioned to regular, full-time roles after the holidays last year, and the company expects to increase that number this year, Amazon said on Thursday.
 </div>
</body>
```

If you can't change the height, you can overflow it using `overflow-y: auto`:

```css
.box1 {
 width: 50%;
 height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.box2 {
 width: 80%;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: blue;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 100px;
}

.box3 {
 background-color: #ccc;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="box1">
 Box 1
  <div class="box2">
  Fixed income, currency, and commodities revenue was $2.65 billion ($2.21 billion expected), up 39% thanks to stronger performance in credit products, especially mortgages, as well as in rates products and client financing.
  Equities revenue came in at $954 million ($1.03 billion expected), down 17% because of lower client activity in cash and derivatives, which the firm said reflected lower market volatility.
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="box3">
  More than 14,000 seasonal positions were transitioned to regular, full-time roles after the holidays last year, and the company expects to increase that number this year, Amazon said on Thursday.
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

u can use a `container` `div` and put `box1` and `box2` inside and `box3` outside it will be the most easy and relevant..

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful too.